# Grails Validateable implementation missing methods

Tags: validation, grails, command

I am using Grails 3.0.11 and am using the *grails.validation.Validateable* class to create a command object. The way I did this:

```
class UserCommand implements Validateable {
String username
String password

static constraints = {
    username(blank: false, minSize: 6)
    password(blank: false, minSize: 6)
}
```

}

But IntelliJ (14.1.1) is underling the class in red, saying that I need to implement missing methods like 'validate' et cetera. If I look up the current [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) of Grails 3.0.11 for command objects and validation, nothing is mentioned that I should implement these methods. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Validateable is a Groovy trait, not an interface, IntelliJ is wrong. Being a trait, basically the valitade method will be *mixed in* to your command class.

I don't know how to solve the underlining IntelliJ problem (I don't use IDE's) but your Groovy code is correct.